# Order view in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In desktop and mobile version, it is the order of the show:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s"> First</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s">Second</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s"> Third</div>
```

[image]

But I want the display order in the mobile display to be from the end to the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st is to use row-reverse.
2nd option is to use order.

So BS order class are like so you can really play with them how ever you want:

```
<div class="order-3 order-lg-1"> First</div>
<div class="order-2">Second</div>
<div class="order-1 order-lg-3">Third</div>
```

Result are different so take the one you wish

### DEMO (USE OF BOOTSTRAP HERE but easily adaptable):

```css
#items{
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  background: red;
}
#items2 {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="items" class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s"> First</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s">Second</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s"> Third</div>
</div>

<div id="items2" class="row">
  <div class="order-3 order-lg-1 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s"> First</div>
  <div class="order-2 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s">Second</div>
  <div class="order-1 order-lg-3 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s"> Third</div>
</div>
```